# Examples and extension in Nuxeo

Tags: content-management-system, jax-rs, nuxeo

I'm trying to set up Nuxeo's examples, but I can't get them working. Does someone succeed in compiling and deploying them ?

I know it uses JAX-RS, but I'm still trying to set up a project with Eclipse to generate bundles, and I'm quite lost. I would be very happy if someone could give me a compiling project, or a link for a simple and clear documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which examples are you trying to run ?
Did you look at http://doc.nuxeo.com/ ?